# Linq Sum with group by

Tags: c#, linq

I am having a table structure with columns

FeesNormal

FeesCustom

Currency

Now i am looking for a SUM function group by currency .

For example 20 USD + 30 EURO + 40 INR  something like this  from this table

I also have to consider the scenario if FeesCustom > 0 I have to ignore FeesNormal for the row

Sample date and expected result is like this

```
  FeesNormal  FeesCustom  Currency
  10          0            USD   
  15          25           USD //in this case can ignore FeesNormal Since FeesCustom is more
  5           10           EUR //same for this row ignore FeesNormal
  10          0            EUR

Expected result  35 USD 20 EUR
```

I able to find sum using the linq

```
 int sum_custom=(int)fee_list.Where(p => p.FeesCustom > 0).Sum(p => p.FeesCustom);
 int sum_normal = (int)fee_list.Where(p => p.FeesCustom ==0).Sum(p => p.FeesNormal);
```

Comment: Do you want your condition to be `FeesCustom > 0` or `FeesCustom != 0`?

Comment: FeeCustom > 0 Then consider FeeCustom in Sum else consider FeeNormal n Sum

Comment: So your final line of code should really be `p.FeesCustom <= 0`, right? To be the opposite of the condition of `> 0`.

Comment: Logic is clear from your answer I think it should be like in answer like if FeeCustom>0 use FeeCustom else FeeNormal

Comment: That's what my answer has, yes. I'm saying that your question isn't as clear as it could be.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It seems to me that you just need a projection from "entry" to "effective fee" which you can sum - something like:

```
var result = source
    .GroupBy(x => x.Currency)
    .Select(g => new {
        Currency = g.Key,
        Total = g.Sum(x => x.FeesCustom > 0 ? x.FeesCustom : x.FeesNormal)
    });
```

That's equivalent to:

```
var result = source
    .GroupBy(x => x.Currency,
             (key, values) => new {
                Currency = key,
                Total = values.Sum(x => x.FeesCustom > 0 ? x.FeesCustom : x.FeesNormal)
             });
```

Or do the transformation earlier:

```
 var result = source
     .Select(x => new {
         x.Currency,
         x.Fee = x => x.FeesCustom > 0 ? x.FeesCustom : x.FeesNormal
     })
     .GroupBy(x => x.Currency, x => x.Fee,
              (key, values) => new { Currency = key, Fee = values.Sum() });
```

Comment: To complete my answer i have to follow one more operation and here is the link for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339611/union-of-2-list-by-groupby

Answer (score 4):

Using Query Syntax:

```
var feeResult = (from fee in fee_list
                group fee by fee.Currency into groupResult
                select new
                {
                    Currency = groupResult.Key,
                    FinalFees = groupResult.Sum(f => f.FeesCustom > 0 ? f.FeesCustom : f.FeesNormal)
                }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have `DataTable` with the mentioned data, you could do this using `Linq`

```
var result = table.AsEnumerable()        
     .GroupBy(x=> x.Field<string>("Currency"))
     .Select(x=> new
      {
          Currency = x.Key,
          Value = x.Sum(s=> Math.Max(s.Field<double>("FeesNormal"), s.Field<double>("FeesCustom "))),

      }      
      .ToList()
```

Comment: How about handling the condition of CustomAmount ? is it possible to do it on single query ?

Comment: What is CustomAmount? can you elaborate more?

Comment: Why assume a datatable when the code in the question doesn't use one? It seems to make things more complicated for no reason... (I also *hope* the OP isn't using `double` values for currency...)

Comment: Question says that table with columns, that's why I assumed it is datatable.

Comment: Well using LINQ to SQL or EF would still be talking about a table, but would make more sense with the sample code given. (Personally I hope that using `DataTable` is pretty rare these days.)