# Union of 2 list by GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists with 1 columns Currency and Total like

```
    list1
      Currency  Total
      USD       10         
      EUR       25  

list2
      Currency  Total
      USD       10         
      EUR       25 
      INR       55
```

How can i get an overall Sum from the two lists in a single list grouped on currency basis like this

```
ListSummary

      Currency Total
      USD       20
      EUR       50
      INR       55
```

The following Linq code is generating the 2 lists for me

```
         var license_sum = licenses.GroupBy(x => x.Currency,
                        (key, values) => new {
                            Currency = key,
                            Total = values.Sum(x => x.FeesCustom == 0 ? x.FeesNormal : x.FeesCustom)
                        });
        var trans_sum = translations.GroupBy(x => x.Currency,
                        (key, values) => new {
                            Currency = key,
                            Total = values.Sum(x => x.FeesCustom == 0 ? x.FeesNormal : x.FeesCustom)
                        });
```

From these 2 i am planning for overool_sum list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Concat` linq extension to concat both lists and then use `GroupBy` to group on currecy..

```
var overool_sum = license_sum.Concat(trans_sum )
                          .GroupBy(x => x.Currency)
                          .Select(x=>  new 
                          {
                            Currency = x.Key,
                            Total = x.Sum(x => x.Total)
                          })
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: i am getting a null exception after trying to navigate to the result. Any known reason for this ? I am checking my input lists are null or not before doing this concat

Comment: Do you have any of these lists (licence_sum, trans_sum) null?

Answer (score 1):

```
var overool_sum = licenses.Concat(translations).GroupBy(x => x.Currency,
                        (key, values) => new {
                            Currency = key,
                            Total = values.Sum(x => x.FeesCustom == 0 ? x.FeesNormal : x.FeesCustom)
                        });
```

Provided that they are the same types - otherwise just `.Select` a common type first :-)

Comment: i am getting a null exception after trying to navigate to the result. Any known reason for this ? I am checking my input lists are null or not before doing this concat

Comment: This is just guess-work without knowing your types... but: Can either .FeesCustom or .FeesNormal be null? Or can the lists become null afterwards? (Both .Concat and .GroupBy are deferred - try .ToList() at the end)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
    class MyClass {
        public string Currency { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
    }

    void Main() {
        var list1 = new List<MyClass>(){
                new MyClass{ Currency = "USD" , Total = 10},
                new MyClass{ Currency = "EUR" , Total = 25},        
            };

        var list2 = new List<MyClass>(){
                new MyClass{ Currency = "USD" , Total = 10},
                new MyClass{ Currency = "EUR" , Total = 25},        
                new MyClass{ Currency = "INR" , Total = 55},        
            };

        var list3 = list1.Concat(list2);

        var list4 = list3.GroupBy(x => x.Currency).Select(y => new MyClass {
            Currency = y.Key,
            Total = y.Sum(z => z.Total)
        });
        Console.WriteLine(list4);

    }
```

Comment: i am getting a null exception after trying to navigate to the result. Any known reason for this ? I am checking my input lists are null or not before doing this concat

Comment: If you copy paste code below in to linqpad, you'll see it works properly.