# Get distinct data from list and add vlaues

Tags: c#, list, linq

suppose I have class in C# called Accounting like that:

```
 public class Accounting 
{
    public string Customer;
    public string Payment;
}
```

And if I have list of Accounting class

```
List<Accounting> AccountList = new List<Accounting>();
```

If AccountList has data like that:

```
Joe : 100
Ali : 200
Machel : 100
Joe : 200
Machel : 500
```

I want to get distinct data only in list and collect the Payment for each Customer like that

```
Joe : 300
Ali : 200
Machel : 600
```

Comment: What have you tried?  This question is rather common.  Please edit your question and add in the code segment demonstrating your best attempt at resolving this yourself, and then explain what result you're getting vs what you expect

Comment: Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count)

Comment: And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338860/linq-sum-with-group-by)

Comment: And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846262/group-by-and-sum-using-linq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you want to `GroupBy` by `Accounting.Customer` and then `Sum` all the `Accounting.Payment`:

```
using System.Linq;

...

var result = AccountList
  .GroupBy(item => item.Customer, item => item.Payment)
  .Select(group => new Accounting() {
     Customer = group.Key,
     Payment = group.Sum(item => decimal.Parse(item)).ToString() 
   })
  .ToList();
```

Please, note, that keep money as `string` is a bad practice; try using `decimal` for `Payment`.